# When textfield become first responder, gesture recogniser not responding, even after resign

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, first-responder, resignfirstresponder, becomefirstresponder

I've probably missed something...
First, I inherited from `UITextField` and added a Tap gesture recogniser to a `UITextField` (in the designated initialiser):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * ges = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pressed:)];
[self addGestureRecognizer:ges];


-(void)pressed:(id)sender
{
    didPressed = YES;
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Then I set my viewController to be the textField delegate and implemented this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UIOneLetterTextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"Key Pressed %@", string);
    textField.text = string;
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
     UITapGestureRecognizer * ges = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:textField action:@selector(pressed:)];
    [textField addGestureRecognizer:ges];
    [self gotoNextTextfield:textField.cellLoc];
    return NO;
}
```

From this point, for some reason, `pressed:` doesn't get called when tapping on the textField.
Any Idea why?

Comment: There are probably other gesture recognizers interfering with it.  Try setting your gesture recognizer's delegate, implementing all the delegate methods, and see which get called.

Comment: Why are you adding the gesture recognizer twice, once in the designated initializer of your derived class, and then again in the delegate method?

Comment: I added again because I was desperate... Aaron, what you suggesting make sense... I will give it a chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate should implement
gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:
and return YES.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why you are using a `UITapGestureRecognizer`? The `UITextFieldDelegate` has a methods that are called whenever a `textField` starts editing :

- `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`
- `textFieldDidBeginEditing:`

Unless you have some code that conflicts with these methods, you do not need a `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Comment: textFieldDidBeginEditing is not good for me because all my text fields is one letter textField - when you type a letter you automatocly jump to the next textField and I want to have a spcial logic when tapping on textfield